# Can't run shellscript with sudo

Tags: sudo, scripts, sh

When I try to run my script like this:

```
sudo ./connector.sh
```

It give me this:

```
sudo: ./connector.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your `myscript.sh` calls `connector.sh`, does `connector.sh` resides in the current directory or in the `PATH` ?

Comment: oh... myscript.sh is connector.sh i just renamed it in the post...

Comment: Whats the output of `stat -c '%A' myscript.sh` ?

Comment: Are trying to execute the script from within the directory containing it?

Comment: The script is in the /root directory, and im execute the script when im en the /root directory.

My script just echo "Hallo";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either add a shebang at the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hallo"
```

And/or set the executable rights

```
sudo chmod +x connector.sh
```

Comment: The simple solutions are the best!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to call the script in this way:

```
sh ./connector.sh
```

you can use any other shell type other than `sh`, depends on your code.

Comment: Or in this way =) +1

Answer (score -2):

no no no.. your problem here is that when you sudo, your current directory is not fully realized. you just have to call your script by the full path, like this(assuming your script is in /tmp)
sudo /tmp/connector.sh